# How Logical expression can be dividend?

Tags: functions, logic, parametric

I work with image processing and I face this equation and I can't understand how logical expression can be **dividend** here??

I need clarification for this part: $δ(y_1 \ne y_2)$

The full equation:  $Ψ^{2D}(y_1,y_2,x_1,x_2) = \frac{δ(y_1 \ne y_2)} { 1+a||RGB_{x1} −RGB_{x2}||_1}$

***Update***

This equation from *A multi-modal graphical model for scene analysis* paper to re-evaluate class similarity using RGB (color value) for adjacent superpixels.

- $Ψ^{2D}$: potential function.
- a: constant, weight of the RGB contrast.
- x, y: adjacent superpixels.

Comment: No answers yet 

Comment: Without some context and refernces... no answer ever.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA This is enough

Comment: Thanks ! As you can see, as long as you have provided some additional info, you have received a fully satisfactory answer :-)

Comment: Your advice is v good because I am new to this website. :)

Comment: It looks like a binary function : $\delta (y_1, y_2)$ that -presumably - returns the value $1$ when $y_1 \ne y_2$ (and presumably : $\delta (y_1, y_2)=0$ when $y_1=y_2$).

Comment: If so, its value is a number and thus perfectly "fitted" to be used as numerator in a fraction.

Comment: We can define the [primitive recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Some_common_primitive_recursive_functions) $\delta(y_1,y_2)$ as : $sg(|y_1-y_2|)$ where $sg$ is the "signum" function.

Comment: I send an email to this paper author and attach this post. I waiting now for their reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numerator equals one, if and only if $y_1 \neq y_2$.

This formula assigns a zero potential to two superpixels that have identical class labels. Note that in this equation, $x_1$ and $x_2$ represent the superpixels 1 and 2, and $y_1$ and $y_2$ are their class labels respectively.

Comment: By the way, the implementation of this paper can not be released because of the Intellectual Properties (IP) rules.

Answer (score 1):

That might be something like the [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).  It would be an indicator function: $1$ when the logical expression is true and $0$ otherwise.  Assuming this interpretation, it could also be rewritten with the Kronecker delta by $\delta(y_1\neq y_2)=1-\delta_{y_1y_2}$.

Without more context, though, it can be hard to say exactly what a given notation means.

Comment: I use "dividend" for point exactly to the problem place. http://prntscr.com/cotavf

Comment: @nagdawi It was a little confusing to use 'dividend' since it could have meant you were asking about logical expressions in dividends in particular, rather than logical expressions appearing as a numeric expression.  Saying "this dividend" would have made it clearer.  Anyway, does this interpretation of the $\delta$ make sense in context?

Comment: Thanks... I will read more about Kronecker delta and try to find link with this function.